# JList select items with all mouse buttons

Tags: java, swing, jlist

how can i make a swing JList to have its items selected with any mousebutton not just the left one?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh just found the function

```
            int s = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            list.setSelectedIndex(s);
```

when you do this in a mouselistener it does the job.